# How to fix breaking changes in MWAA 2.7.2

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I created a new MWAA environment using v2.7.2
All my DAGs which were working fine in v2.6.3 are broken now.

`from airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookOperator ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.slack'`

I have updated my requirements file for this new environment, saw this in [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/v2.7.2/requirements/requirements.txt)

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.2/constraints-3.11.txt"

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.0.1
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==5.3.1
```

I expected that would be sufficient.
What do I need to change to install airflow.providers.slack correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The airflow slack provider is missing in your environment. Add below line in requirements.txt

```
apache-airflow-providers-slack==8.1.0
```

Full requirements.txt

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.2/constraints-3.11.txt"

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.0.1
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==5.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-slack==8.1.0
```

Comment: I was able to add that but now I am getting this error                        send_slack_notification = SlackWebhookOperator(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 420, in apply_defaults
    raise AirflowException(f"missing keyword argument {missing_args.pop()!r}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: missing keyword argument 'slack_webhook_conn_id'

Comment: Looks like http_conn_id has been replaced by slack_webhook_conn_id in SlackWebhookOperator.

Comment: `http_conn_id` deprecated in **6.0.0** and removed in **8.0.0** of [Slack Provider](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-slack/stable/changelog.html)